# Convert bytes array to int python wrong result

Tags: python, arrays, integer

I know this should be easy, but I just can't get the syntax right for python.

My int is not converted correctly. This is the output of my 2 print statements. My output should be `9718` instead of `959918392`.

```
bytearray(b'9718')
959918392
```

This is my conversion. I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

```
print(size)
print(int.from_bytes(size, byteorder='big'))
```

Comment: @apknusel That's definitely asking something else

Comment: yea, i made a mistake and assumed my bytearray was bytes[], but it acctly contained ascii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried assumes the number is directly encoded as bytes. You actually want to parse it from ascii, which you can do like this:

```py
int(b'9718'.decode('ascii'))
```